# Instagram tag search - filter for images and tags after a certain time or id

Tags: api, instagram

I am using the Instagram API to fetch a list of photos tagged with a certain hashtag. I've got a real-time subscription set up so it will notify me whenever new photos have been posted. However, I have to fetch the new results myself.

My problem: When I request the list of recently tagged photos, I get a large list and I don't want to process all of the results in the recent list every time I do this. The api docs say I can pass these optional parameters, but they seem counter-intuitive. They seem to be the opposite of what I would expect:

```
MIN_ID  Return media before this min_id.
MAX_ID  Return media after this max_id.
```

If I keep track of the most recent media id I've seen in my recent requests, how do I construct my next request to only return results newer than that id?

I've posted two photos with a test hashtag. When I use the following url (with my real access_token in it), I get back a json response listing both of those photos:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/weirdtest/media/recent?access_token=xxx
```

The two photos have these ids:

```
221201236060507271_179249322
221190263853517857_179249322
```

How do I construct a query that returns only the newer of those two photos?

Comment: Please provide a link to the API docs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tack the most recent ID you've seen on the end, using the `MAX_ID` request parameter:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/weirdtest/media/recent?access_token=xxx&MAX_ID=221201236060507271_179249322
```

This should tell Instagram, *"The most recent photo I've seen is 221201236060507271_179249322, return only newer photos"*.